# How to handle Outlook's "Outlook is using an old copy of your data file (.ost). Exit outlook and blablabla" error at an API level using VBScript?

Tags: api, vbscript, outlook

I have created some automated scripts in VBS to execution some tasks automatically on a remote virtual machine. However, whenever I want to email the result to the people that it concerns, Outlook, on start, gives me this error, preventing me from sending any email. The script could not send anything until I manually dismiss this message (but I did not have to actually solve this). The client machine that sends email is a remote virtual machine. It is managed by a driver machine (another remote virtual machine) in such way that every time a new build comes out the client machine gets restored to a checkpoint and downloads the build and installs it and then tests it. It seems that since it is using a snapshot, the outlook data file will have to be out-of-sync with what's on the server, possibly causing the aforementioned error.

Does anyone know how to handle this error in VBScript? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to avoid the use of outlook.ost at all. Turn off cached mode (for Exchange) or turn off any Send/Receive settings for folders. Close Outlook and rename outlook.ost to .old.
Open Outlook and check too see if outlook.ost is not created again.